# C# --headless print-to-pdf with Microsoft edge(chromium) won't work using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: .net, microsoft-edge, google-chrome-headless

It works when using Chrome.
I wanted Edge as a back-up for printing HTML to PDF as it is pre-installed on Windows.
`Process.ExitCode` gives out 1002 and no error in `BeginErrorReadLine`. And no PDF is generated at output path unlike Chrome.

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")
     string FilePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = FilePath;
string pdfFile = //output-path(in Temp);
string htmlFile = //input-file-path(in Temp);

process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--headless --print-to-pdf-no-header --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf={pdfFile} {htmlFile}";

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(process.ExitCode);
```

Comment: A few things to note: Even in Chrome `--print-to-pdf-no-header` is the old flag name: it's now `--no-pdf-header-footer`: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless#headless-specific-command-line-flags I don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but it is different between the list of arguments the code is using and https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: yeah removing those old flags still fails. The exact same code with chrome file path works with no problems.

Comment: executing the whole thing in cmd also works      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless  --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf="pdfFile" "htmlFile"